# Duplication of Credentials When Register

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone see why my code inserts register credentials twice in my table, `action_registration.php`. I'm currently learning how to make my login more secure as I was testing I noticed that the input for registration is inserted twice to my table.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['register'])){

// connection handler link
$conreg = new mysqli('localhost', 'x', '123456', 'db.x.x');

// in case theres no link to connection
if  (mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} // end error if

else // when connection is okay
{
    echo "we good on connection so far";
    echo "<br>";

}     // end else connection okay

$userreg = $_POST['username'];

$passreg =$_POST['password'];
$phash = sha1(sha1($passreg."salt")."salt");

$emailreg = $_POST['email'];

$sqlreg = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (`username` , `password`,  `email` , `comment_value`, `Member_Since`)  VALUES  (?,?,?,'1' , now() ) ";

// prepare link, and function statement
$stmtreg = $conreg->prepare($sqlreg);

// bind variable parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtreg, "sss", $userreg , $phash , $emailreg ); // bind variables s' is a string for username , s' is a string for password

if  ( !mysqli_execute($stmtreg) )
{

echo "Died on  bind variable parameters";
die( 'stmt error: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmtreg) );

} // end error if

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtreg);  //excute the preapared register statement

 //$cookie_value = $user;
 //setcookie($cookie_name , $cookie_value, time() + (2000), "/");

  //header("Location: reg_.php");
  echo '<font color="green">Please Login Now</font>';

 } // end isset register

 ?>
```

The form calls `action_registration.php`:

```
<table>
<form   action ="actions/action_registration.php"  method="POST" >
<tr>
<td> Username :</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password :</td>
    <td><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" >  </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Email :</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Email"id="email" name="email"  size="20"/></td>
    <br/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td><td>
   <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"></td>  </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
```

Comment: Execute query two times 1) `mysqli_execute()` and 2)`mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtreg);` ANd well `mysqli_execute()` is deprecated and will be removed. CHeck http://php.net/mysqli_execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the query twice:

```
if  ( !mysqli_execute($stmtreg) ) //<--here
{

echo "Died on  bind variable parameters";   
die( 'stmt error: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmtreg) );

} // end error if


mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtreg); //<-- and here
```

You can simply drop the second call.

You should probably change the 1st call to use `mysqli_stmt_execute` as well, `mysqli_execute` is just an alias: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-execute.php

Comment: @Saty well the 1st call is part of OPs error handling, so it makes sense to drop the second. I added a note about `mysqli_execute`

Comment: Well document says __`mysqli_execute() is deprecated and will be removed.`__ so apply check on second call and remove first one

Comment: @Saty we appear to be saying that exact same thing.